# How do I change the outputEncoding for the Mule file connector 'On New or Updated File'?

Tags: mule4

I'm new on Mule and are trying to set upp a flow that monitors a folder. Move and rename incoming textfiles and converting the file to encoding ISO-8859-1.

I can't get the outputEncoding to work. The file remains with encoding UTF-8.

This is my configuration XML I'm using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<file:config name="File_Config" doc:name="File Config" doc:id="b26e348c-074d-4fec-8af8-6b0952cfb5ec" defaultWriteEncoding="ISO-8859-1" >
<file:connection/>
</file:config>
<configuration-properties doc:name="Configuration properties" doc:id="e3ba4c3e-0ccd-446f-a844-991c64be0318" file="gross.properties" />
<flow name="sunnyftpFlow" doc:id="1c20d716-1aa4-4fba-b15e-f38f461273d6">
<file:listener doc:name="On New or Updated File" doc:id="53c0f78c-5f91-47ce-a32b-49433b4a49fd" directory="C:\FTP\SUNNYFTP" config-ref="File_Config" moveToDirectory="C:\FTP\TMP" renameTo="#['TEST_'++ now() as DateTime as String {format: 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'} ++ '_'++ message.attributes.fileName]" outputEncoding="ISO-8859-1" outputMimeType="text/flatfile">
<scheduling-strategy >
<fixed-frequency/>
</scheduling-strategy>
</file:listener>
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="4c7c0227-e392-4403-8f8d-55de1c314b92"/>
</flow>
</mule>
```

I was expecting the outputEncoding in the row below to solve the problem.

```
<file:listener doc:name="On New or Updated File" doc:id="53c0f78c-5f91-47ce-a32b-49433b4a49fd" directory="C:\FTP\SUNNYFTP" config-ref="File_Config" moveToDirectory="C:\FTP\TMP" renameTo="#['TEST_'++ now() as DateTime as String {format: 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'} ++ '_'++ message.attributes.fileName]" **outputEncoding="ISO-8859-1"** outputMimeType="text/flatfile">
```

Comment: What is the actual issue? You are just saying that there is an encoding problem but didn't show any details. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I guess you need to provide a sample input, actual output and expected output that shows the encoding issue.

Comment: I put a text file with encoding UTF-8 in folder C:\FTP\SUNNYFTP\. After processing the file moved to folder C:\FTP\TMP\ is still in encoding UTF-8. I was expecting it to have changed to encoding ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `outputEncoding` overrides the value of the encoding but doesn't actually transform the data to be in that encoding. For that you have to use a transformation and set the encoding in the output:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/flatfile encoding="ISO-8859-1"
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried outputMimeType,. It did not work. I'll try to use a transformation.

Comment: I'll remove that suggestion.